# How to copy geo spatial data from Azure CosmosDB to text file by Azure data factory?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I now need to copy geo spatial data from Azure CosmosDB to a text file in azure data lake store using azure data factory.

The spatial data in cosmos DB is like this:

```
{
  "Longitude": "5.2926",
  "Latitude": "60.2219",
  "Location": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      5.2926,
      60.2219
    ]
  }
}
```

First I tried to load the "Location" data directly by ADF, and it failed, due to ADF doesn't support the spatial data format.

Then I add the structure in the dataset of ADF to assign it as string:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "structure": [
            {
                "name": "Location.type",
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "Location.coordinates",
                "type": "String"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The pipeline works, however, the Location.coordinates is exported as NULL.

Obviously, ADF doesn't recognize the spatial data, and assign NULL to export.

Anyone familiar with this transfer? Or how to do convert from spatial format to string?

Comment: According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-create-datasets#a-namestructureadataset-structure), the Data Factory supports the following values for providing type information in structure: Int16, Int32, Int64, Single, Double, Decimal, Byte[], Bool, String, Guid, Datetime, Datetimeoffset, and Timespan. It doesn't support spatial data(array) format. Also we couldn't convert the type in the datafactory.  Have you consider changing the type to string when you insert the data into the CosmosDB?

Comment: Coverting the spatial data to string could be possible in cosmosdb, but it need more work on cosmos side. Anyway, it seems that the spatial data can not be converted to string automatically.

Comment: I agree with you. I suggest you could firstly convert the spatial data to string before insert into the cosmosDB. Then you could use the ADF to copy the data to text file.

Comment: @BrandoZhang-MSFT, I have another question about cosmosdb, can you help have a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45029228/how-to-improve-the-performance-when-copying-data-from-cosmosdb